# when should I #define NO_XSLOCKS

Tags: perl, preprocessor, xs

`NO_XSLOCKS` allows the usage of some error checking macros in XS code when combined with `#include XSUB.h`. However, its use seems to go beyond that. It was recently suggested that I add it to my XS file for better compatibility with ActiveState perl, with [this issue](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=62150) given as an example.

What else does `#define NO_XSLOCKS` do, and when should I use it in my XS code?

Comment: You have to define `NO_XSLOCKS` if you want to use the [`XCPT_*` macros](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Exception-Handling) for excpetion handling. Additionally `NO_XSLOCKS` disables the replacement of C library functions with Perl wrappers. I have no idea why the same macro is used for seemingly different things, and where its name comes from. Adding a bounty to hopefully attract some attention.

Comment: http://www.tagwith.com/question_569899_when-should-i-define-no-xslocks

Comment: @HaltlolXD Why did you post that? That his his exact question posted on another site.

Comment: Yes, and I am also wondering this, so keep an eye on both ;) @JaredBurrows

Comment: I should have been more clear. Look at the dates, posted same day, relatively the same time. This post is the original and "tag with.com" simply scans the web for this kind of content. That is why I asked "why did you post this?"